# Regex validating eight or more char string that must contain at least two non-alphabetic characters

Tags: java, regex

I am validating a password string that must consist of eight characters or more and must contain at least two non-alphabetic (i.e., not `A-Za-z`) characters using regular expression.

The code I have so far is

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?=2.*[^a-z[A-Z]]).{8,})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(pass);
```

I don't know whether my expression is correct.

Comment: *i dont know whether my expression is correct*: then you should test it before asking.

Comment: maybe this can help you [`^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[^a-zA-Z]{2,}).{8,}$`](https://regex101.com/r/R4Bv0h/1) beside you can test your regex in this web site https://regex101.com/

Comment: thank you very much.i'll try

Comment: In that expression if I add numeric character the expression doesn't count it as an non alphabetic character

Comment: it do https://regex101.com/r/434gvx/1 can you please share some correct inputs please?

Comment: ohh it's works thanks

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to validate my password with eight characters or more and must contain at least two non-alphabetic (i.e., not A-Z) characters

You may use

```
s.matches("(?=(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}).{8,}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/434gvx/2).

Another way of writing the same

```
s.matches("(?=.{8})(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}.*")
```

**Explanation**

- `^` - (not necessary in `.matches` as the method requires a full string match) - start of string
- `(?=` - start of a positive lookahead that requires, immediately to the right of the current location,

  - `(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}` - a non-capturing group that matches 2 consecutive occurrences of:

    - `[^a-zA-Z]*` - any 0+ chars other than ASCII letters
    - `[a-zA-Z]`  - an ASCII letter
- `)` - end of the lookahead
- `.{8,}` - any 8 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - (not necessary in `.matches` as the method requires a full string match) - end of string

In `(?=.{8})(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}.*` pattern, the first lookahead requires at least 8 chars, then at least two letters are requires using the `(?:[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}` pattern, and then `.*` matches the rest of the string.